# Store template data as a string in Ember

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm using Ember and an upload plugin. The plugin allows me to overwrite it's HTML template through a property as a string.

```
$("#fileUpload").dropzone({
   previewTemplate: ' some huge html string',
});
```

Adding in a string of HTML would be difficult to support and look awful so I created an external Handlebars .hbs file which houses the template HTML.

Normally I would populate this template without an issue using `$.get()`. However, I imagine that Ember has a way to do this intelligently. I've dug through the API and haven't seen anything specific to help me with this.

I would think something like `var template = Ember.Handlebars.get('upload.hbs');` would work but it returns an error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just trying to summarise what you are doing, after clarification from my previous *(deleted)* answer.

- You have a plugin, that accepts a plain html string.
- The html string you want to provide to the plugin is very long.
- You want to store the string as an external file, to avoid including in your regular code.
- The html string is **not a Handlebars template** though you store it as `upload.hbs`.
- You were hoping that Ember would have a method for loading remote templates, that you could use to avoid using jQuery GET.

**No method to load remote templates:**

The reality is that **Ember does not have a built in method for loading remote template files** in their raw format. It does however allow you to precompile handlebars templates to JavaScript that can be included as a regular `script` tag. But as **you are not using a handlebars template** pre-compilation would do nothing more than wrap your html string in some JavaScript.

- There is no such [feature documented](http://emberjs.com/api/modules/ember-handlebars-compiler.html).
- Nor is there in [the source code](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js).

**Why `Ember.Handlebars.get('upload.hbs')` won't work:**

[This method](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.html#method_get) is used to get the content of **locally included** templates. That means it only looks for templates that exist in the `Ember.TEMPLATES` array or from the `<script>` tags of type `text/x-handlebars`.

**The reason why Ember does not have the ability to load remote template files:**

It does not have a method for loading in raw handlebars files because:

- Many people use the precompiled handlebars files (which can be loaded as remote JS)
- Many people use the inline `<script type="text/x-handlebars"></script>` tags. 
  *It's notable that you cannot use the `src` attribute of `script` to pull in a handlebars template, because browsers will only accept `src` for `text/javascript`.*
- Ember relies on jQuery, and as jQuery provides suitable methods `GET` & `AJAX` it's trivial to implement in conjunction with `Ember.Handlebars.compile("<strong>Hello {{name}}</strong>")`, if required.

**Your template:**

As you are not using a Handlebars template and you are just loading html, the correct approach, as you suspected is simply [jQuery `GET`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/).

```
$.get( "dropZoneUploadTemplate.html", function(template) {
    $("#fileUpload").dropzone({
        previewTemplate: template
    });
});
```

**Summary**

While it is nice to use Ember where possible, this simply is a jQuery task. Sorry it's not the answer you were hoping for. Maybe in future versions of Ember it will include such as feature.

---

**Making the uploader into an Ember Component:**

You could turn your uploader into an Ember Component like this, and combine with the jQuery GET to take care of loading in your html.

```
App.FileUploadComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile("<input type='file' />"),
    didInsertElement: function(){
        var c = this.$(":file");
        $.get("dropZoneUploadTemplate.html", function(template){
            c.dropzone({ previewTemplate: template });
        });
    }
});
```

This would mean every time you want to use the upload control in your Ember templated view you can simply do:

```
{{file-upload}}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Very nice answer. Does this conflict with Ember's routing when using a `GET` request?

Comment: @ZachShallbetter Thanks. No jQuery GET won't conflict at all with Ember's routing. Ember's routing is only concerned with the `location.hash` segment of the current page. In other words, (assume your Ember app is loaded from `index.html`) Ember will watch for changes to `index.html/#/SomeRoute` to say `index.html/#/AnotherRoute` essentially anything past the `#`. But your jQuery request will be to something like `template.html` and as such is out of scope. You can free use jQuery GET and AJAX as normal.

Comment: @ZachShallbetter Did my explanation of the route scope with regards to GET make sense? Let me know if there is anything you are still unsure about.

Comment: yes it did make sense. However, when I perform a GET request it returns the default base template as opposed to the specific file. I'm under the impression that it has something to do with the routing.

Comment: @ZachShallbetter can you put the code of your GET request please?

Comment: @ZachShallbetter I have managed to look at the JSFiddle now. What happens when you go to `http://yourserver/distillery/static/distillery/script/app/templates/upload.hbs` directly in the address bar? I would also recommend changing `.hbs` to `.html`.

Comment: It returns an error. This is what caused me to think there was a problem with the routing. Sorry, I should have mentioned that.

Assertion failed: The URL '/static/distillery/script/app/templates/upload.hbs' did not match any routes in your application

Comment: @ZachShallbetter I think I have found the problem. Are you [doing this](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-the-location-api/)? It seems like you are serving your application to any inputted url, which will prevent you for accessing files, unless you configure your server to exclude certain routes.

Comment: Yeah, it was set to `location: history` I changed it to `location: none` while it does now redirect me back to index when I do the GET request, it still pulls the site's index.html template instead of upload.hbs

Comment: @ZachShallbetter It's not a problem with Ember, it's your webserver which is configured to return your Ember App for **any** inputted URL. Setting `location:history` to `location:none` won't affect what the webserver is returning. Check your web server configuration and have it exclude sending the Ember Application for certain urls.